# Example of programmatically creating/restoring an EBS snapshot using AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am not finding much information through google on examples to do this in code, everything shows an example using cli tool.

For backup, correct me if I am wrong, here is what I have(untested)

```
AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey);
AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(cred);
CreateSnapshotRequest snapshotRequest = new CreateSnapshotRequest(volumeId,description);
ec2.createSnapshot(snapshotRequest);
```

From what I understand, this goes to an S3 repository that I have no control over. I am assuming I can do some type of 'list snapshots' and choose one to restore.

I want to be able to restore an EBS using a snapshot, I found some information regarding creating a new EBS from snapshot using createVolume or something similar. I want to restore current EBS with specific snapshot.

Comment: You can create a new volume from an snapshot, but you can't restore a snapshot into an existing volume. You'd need to restore to new, swap volumes, delete old volume.

Comment: I see, any chance you can provide the code to document that process :)

Comment: Also better stop instance first, avoids lots possible of OS issues, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to automate the snapshot process and need to be able to load snapshots as well(using sdk)

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I tried replacing my EC2 volume with a new one created from snapshot and it wouldn't allow me to mount it. Gave me the following error, mount: /dev/xvdj is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdj

Answer (score 1):

For Creating a Snapshot you can refer below:

//From Local:

```
            //I guess it's resolved from your end. But to help other. Below is the code to Create a snapshot from C# AWS SDK
            //Download AWSSDK.Core/AWSSDK.EC2/AWSSDK.S3 from nuget Package Manager and use the below code for reference
            IAmazonEC2 client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsAccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.APSouth1); 
            //Change Region end point based on your location
            CreateSnapshotsRequest createSnapshotsRequest = new CreateSnapshotsRequest();
            createSnapshotsRequest.InstanceSpecification = new InstanceSpecification
            {
                InstanceId = "instance id",
                ExcludeBootVolume = false
            };

            //tags can be added using below:
            //createSnapshotsRequest.TagSpecifications = new List<TagSpecification>
            //{
            //    new TagSpecification
            //    {
            //        Tags= new List<Tag>{
            //            new Tag
            //            {
            //                Key = tagKey,
            //                Value = tagValue
            //            }
            //        },
            //        ResourceType="snapshot"
            //    }
            //};

            var response = client.CreateSnapshots(createSnapshotsRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(response.HttpStatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Snapshots);


            //If you are running the app on EC2 then use below:
            //I guess it's resolved from your end. But to help other. Below is the code to Create a snapshot from C# AWS SDK
            //Download AWSSDK.Core/AWSSDK.EC2/AWSSDK.S3 from nuget Package Manager and use the below code for reference
            KeyValuePair<string, IAMSecurityCredentialMetadata> iamSecurityCredentialMetadata = EC2InstanceMetadata.IAMSecurityCredentials.FirstOrDefault();
            IAmazonEC2 client = new AmazonEC2Client(iamSecurityCredentialMetadata.Value.AccessKeyId, iamSecurityCredentialMetadata.Value.SecretAccessKey, iamSecurityCredentialMetadata.Value.Token, EC2InstanceMetadata.Region);
            CreateSnapshotsRequest createSnapshotsRequest = new CreateSnapshotsRequest();
            createSnapshotsRequest.InstanceSpecification = new InstanceSpecification
            {
                InstanceId = EC2InstanceMetadata.InstanceId,
                ExcludeBootVolume = false
            };

            //tags can be added using below:
            //createSnapshotsRequest.TagSpecifications = new List<TagSpecification>
            //{
            //    new TagSpecification
            //    {
            //        Tags= new List<Tag>{
            //            new Tag
            //            {
            //                Key = tagKey,
            //                Value = tagValue
            //            }
            //        },
            //        ResourceType="snapshot"
            //    }
            //};

            var response = client.CreateSnapshots(createSnapshotsRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(response.HttpStatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Snapshots);
```